# How can a private network be created besides Mainnet and Testnet?

Tags: stake-pool, testnet

I've came across this 2 year old question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516758/can-a-private-cardano-network-be-created), I'm starting a side project at work to explore the potential of Cardano.

There is an old documentation page that mentions **cardano-sl** component which has been currently decomposed into several others.

This other page(https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano), reads:

> Alternatively, you can spin up your own custom Cardano network, but that is outside the scope of this guide.

Bottom line the question is whether it **is possible to create custom private Cardano networks** besides the mainnet and testnet networks, and if so, where can we find documentation about that process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do that. You can edit genesis and config files to your taste.
Creating a local network is the purpose of the script [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/scripts/shelley-from-scratch/mkfiles.sh) and there is a guide [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/62485960494d914f8efd06ed0d8357d41a8f9d26/doc/reference/shelley-genesis.md).

There is also a similar set of config files for jumpstarting in Alonzo [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab/local-cluster/cluster-data/cardano-node-shelley)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrej Novikov, I'm currently following https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/62485960494d914f8efd06ed0d8357d41a8f9d26/doc/reference/shelley-genesis.md which is comprehensive guide on how to Create a Shelley Blockchain from scratch.

Comment: @Andrej welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your answer here! I'd recommend to elaborate a bit, especially when your answer talks about what you "believe" rather than what you "know". It may help to look at some other answers on the Stack Exchange network to see the average length and what's considered a good answer!

Comment: Are there equivalent instructions for creating a fresh/local alanzo-era blockchain from scratch?

Comment: @robertwb I'm not aware if there are instructions, but I've updated my response to include a link to the local network configuration files targeting alonzo

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very familiar where you would find the right documentation, but **it certainly is possible** to have multiple `cardano-node` be connecting to each other, forming a private network. Such a network could also be configured as you like and run with completely different parameters.

One starting point maybe is to have a look how the `cardano-wallet` does launch a cluster of `cardano-node`s locally for testing purposes: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/blob/master/lib/shelley/exe/local-cluster.hs
This document also has some explanations on how the network is configured and what data (faucets) gets prepared in the code.